# Warnings on nx serve Application(Angular v12.0.0) on Nrwl NX Monorepo( v12.3.5)

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have 2 warnings when starting angular 12 application NX Monorepo.  I am sure those warnings were not present when launching Angular 12 Application on NX Monorepo 12.3.4, so they appeared in NX Monorepo 12.3.5.

Question is did I made some mistake or is this NX issue or how can I fix this?

```
Option "hmrWarning" is deprecated: No longer has an effect.
Option "servePathDefaultWarning" is deprecated: No longer has an effect.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main",
    "nx": "nx",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "nx workspace-lint && ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "nx affected:build",
    "affected:e2e": "nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:test": "nx affected:test",
    "affected:lint": "nx affected:lint",
    "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "nx affected",
    "format": "nx format:write",
    "format:write": "nx format:write",
    "format:check": "nx format:check",
    "update": "nx migrate latest",
    "workspace-generator": "nx workspace-generator",
    "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
    "help": "nx help"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "12.3.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/jest": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/linter": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/nest": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/node": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/tao": "12.3.5",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.3.5",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.8",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.19.0",
    "cypress": "^7.3.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "26.2.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.4.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.5",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the `Option "hmrWarning" is deprecated: No longer has an effect.`, you may check the `angular.json` file if it has the `hmrWarning` attribute indicated.